# UWP C# SQL Webservice GridView triggers

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, win-universal-app, uwp

i have class created for data retrieval

I have XAML code with gridview and cs code which connects to SQL webservice and i can get data from SQL :-)

my gridview has

textblock - data from sql table

checkbox

textbox

I would like to have some actions on the checkbox and textboxes.  How do I get my textboxes to become visible upon checkbox click?

I have got this code working in other apps without gridviews, but I can't get it to work here.  how do I reference the event_handler inside the gridview

XAML example

```
<GridView x:Name="GreenQuestionGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="Green" Margin="0,40,0,0">
             <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <Grid Height="40" Width="600" >
                         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                             <TextBlock Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding question_green}" />
                             <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox" Checked="chkBox_Checked" Unchecked="chkBox_Unchecked" Indeterminate="chkBox_Indeterminate" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsThreeState="True"  />
                             <TextBox x:Name="txtBox" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="200"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                         </StackPanel>
                     </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </GridView.ItemTemplate>
         </GridView>
```

here is code that works in other app, but this needs to reference the gridview

```
private void chkBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {         
         if (chkbox.IsChecked == null)
         {
             txtbox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         }
         else
         {
             txtbox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the CheckBox you need also the event CheckBox_Unchecked to hide it again.

`<CheckBox Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" ... />`

IsChecked is a nullable type you didnt even checked if it's true. Your code will hide the txtbox so long as the IsChecked is not null.

```
private static void ToggleTextBoxVisibility(object sender) {
    if(!(sender is CheckBox)) {
        return;
    }
    CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;

    foreach(var child in ((checkBox.Parent as StackPanel).Children)) {
        if(!(child is TextBox)) {
            continue;
        }

        TextBox textBox = child as TextBox;
        if(checkBox.IsChecked.HasValue && checkBox.IsChecked.Value) {
            textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        } else {
            textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}

private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ToggleTextBoxVisibility(sender);
}

private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ToggleTextBoxVisibility(sender);
}
```

A clean solution would be to control it with a binding to a property in your viewmodel.

Comment: that's awesome!!  thanks for that :-)
as my checkbox is a threestate check, would it be possible to have it also remove with the 3rd state?

Comment: The textbox removed, or hide the checkbox?

Comment: remove it when checkbox ticked and unticked, shown in 3rd state
currently my working app has the checkbox collapsed on load 
then the code checks for indeterminate state 
" if (chkbox.IsChecked == null)
and then brings the textbox visible
 if (chkbox.IsChecked == null)
         {
             txtbox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         }
         else
         {
             txtbox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         }

Comment: hello http://stackoverflow.com/users/4225487/Stefan please come back and be happy